# Как вывести массив без максимального и минимального числа?

Tags: python

Вот мой код:

```
A, B, C, D = map(int, input().split())
d = [A, B, C, D]
K = max(d)
L = min(d)
```

теоретически макс. число - А, мин. число - В
Как теперь получить список без них?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
d.remove(K)
d.remove(L)
```

Но удаляется только первое вхождение, поэтому если есть вероятность, что макс/мин встречается больше одного раза, придется применить какуй-нибудь костыль. Например, такой:

```
while K in d:
    d.remove(K)
```

Или еще какой-нибудь.

Или так еще в одну строчку

```
d = [num for num in d if (num != K and num != L)]
```

Comment: в смысле первое вхождение??

Comment: в смысле если число встречается в списке более одного раза, то удалится только первое

Comment: извините, я вообще валенок
Вот например есть массив 5, 6, 8, 5
Удаляю макс и мин 
d.remove(K)
d.remove(L)

Comment: и остается 5 и 6?

Comment: Все, помогло, спасибо огромное!

Comment: последний вариант должен быть самый быстрый, потому что меньше всего проходов по списку.

Answer (score 1):

Используем `filter`:

```py
*res, = filter(lambda x: x != K and x != L, d)
print(res)
```

или так:

```
*res, = filter(L.__ne__, filter(K.__ne__, d))
```

Но, конечно, по читабельности, первый вариант лучше.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [3, 6, 1, 8] #создаём список с n количеством чисел
list.sort() #сортирует список от младшего к старшему
list.pop(0) #удаляем первый элемент
list.pop() #удаляем последний элемент
print(list) #выводим список на экран
```

Или если необходимо удалить не только макс и мин, но и их дубли:

```
list = [3, 7, 5, 2, 4, 3, 2, 9, 6, 8, 8, 9]
list.sort()
a = list[0]
b = list[len(list) - 1]
ind_a = 0
ind_b = 0
for n in list:
    if n == a:
        ind_a += 1
for m in list:
    if m == b:
        ind_b += 1
for o in range(ind_a):
    list.pop(0)
for p in range(ind_b):
    list.pop()
print(list)
```

Comment: Зачем же сортировать список, если требуется всего лишь найти максимум и минимум?

Comment: Потому что задача не найти их, а вывести список без них

Comment: Вообще никак не "потому что". Ну или так - "потому что я придумал такой дурацкий алгоритм и мне кажется, что это хорошо". Вот это будет правильный ответ. Если вам, допустим, в книге нужно прочитать только примечания, вы не только читаете всю книгу целиком, но и делаете конспект? Оцените затраты на сортировку списка в пару миллионов элементов и сравните их с простым поиском максимума и минимума.

Comment: Я просто привык сортировать список, но вы правы, не стоит так делать